# Un terme pour désigner le fait qu'on désigne à la fois un texte et son auteur

Tags: linguistique, figure-de-style

Dans de nombreuses langues, il arrive, en général par souci de concision, qu'on désigne un ouvrage non par son titre original mais en substantivant le nom de l'auteur.

Exemple:

- "le" Littré (titre original: Dictionnaire de la langue française)
- "le" Gaffiot

Il arrive inversement qu'on désigne un auteur par son ouvrage principal. Je n'ai pas d'exemple qui me vienne en français, mais c'est assez courant en hébreu:

Exemple (en hébreu):

- "Le" Nefesh haHayim, "le" Sfat Emet, etc.

Je serais intéressé de savoir s'il existe des termes pour désigner ces faits linguistiques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On appelle ça **l'éponyme** qui est le fait de donner son nom à quelque chose. Le mot éponyme s'emploie pour une personne qui donne son nom à une œuvre, un créateur d'entreprise (Renault,...), un scientifique donnant son nom à une unité (Ampère, Tesla, ...)

Comment: Ceci ne répond que partiellement à la question... mais je n'arrive pas à trouver d'exemple de l'inverse donc je ne sais même pas si cela a un nom...

Comment: Pour la première partie de la question, c'est bien le terme éponyme. Pour la seconde, en consultant Wikipedia, il semble que ce que je cherche est le terme "antonomase" (quoique ma question soit plus spécifique). Ma question soulève le cas particulier où le nom commun d'une oeuvre connue s'emploie pour désigner le nom propre de l'auteur.  Effectivement je n'ai pas encore trouvé d'exemple en langue française...